# Is it possible to have a parameter within a parameter when using Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: api, powershell

I'm trying to configure my websites using the integrated API for Incapsula and I've run into a situation where the particular setting I'm trying to configure has it's own parameter that can be set.  I'm already using a parameter to pass through with the API call when using `Invoke-WebRequest`.

If I only want to configure a single setting, the parameter looks like this:

```
$params = @{account_id='123456';api_id='98765';api_key='furhtjf-adkjoei-ekjmvnt';`
site_id='999999';param='async_validation';value='true'
}
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest https://my.incapsula.com/api/prov/v1/sites/performance/advanced `
-Method Post -Body $params
```

As you can see here in this screenshot there are multiple parameters that I can specify:

[image: Incapsula Parameters]

I can make an API call for each setting that I want to configure, but that's just not efficient.  So, how can I set all of them at the same time?

Comment: Can you not just add each parameter value pair to your `$params` hash and send them all together?

Comment: @arco444 No, I tried that.  I realized that my $params was incorrect above and I fixed it.  You can now see that I have to specify 'param' and 'value' separately.